# Add row with innerHTML and autocomplete not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to insert input box with id as tags.
After insert, I need the auto complete to function.
tried many ways but the input with tags cannot auto complete.

```
function addRow(row) {

    var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var newRow= table.insertRow((1));
    var row = newRow.insertCell(1)"

    row.innerHTML+="<INPUT id =tags>"; 

 }

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    "abc",
    "bcd",
    "EGF"
        ];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
                });
    });
```

Where shall I place my autocomplete to enable the function for the new ?

Comment: I believe you mistyped a `;` into `"` (line 6), the syntax highlighter revealed that.

Comment: which line?? it suppose to work this way right?

Comment: var row = newRow.insertCell(1)"

Comment: And I see many problems: (1) `addRow` is never referenced (2) don't see why you need to use `innerHTML` if you have jQuery (3) appended HTML is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row.innerHTML+="<INPUT id =tags>";` this row

should be

`row.innerHTML+='<INPUT id="tags" />';`

and make sure you call $( "#tags" ).autocomplete() after you addRow

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function addRow(row) {
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var newRow= table.insertRow((1));
  var row = newRow.insertCell(1)"

  row.innerHTML+='<INPUT id="tags">'; 

   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
     });
```

}